# Manejar resultado de JSON en JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Alguien conoce como leer en JavaSript, cuando el resultado del json luego del encode es Datos{"a":"xya","b":"xyb","c":"xyc"} y no {"a":"xya","b":"xyb","c":"xyc"}, sin el enunciado "Datos". Al momento de transformar JSON.parse(data); me da error y ya lo intento de mil formas sin éxitos. Agradecería su gentil ayuda. Saludos.

[image: Modelo: Consulta a la base de datos]
[image: Controller: json_encode]
[image: Js: despliegue en el elemento html]
[image: Código de ejecutarSQL]

Comment: Esa coma al final del ultimo json que dejas viene despues del encode, o solo la colocaste para separar el json con el siguiente parrado.

Comment: la coma es para separar la idea en el texto

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imágenes de código fuente. Publica directamente el texto del fuente (copiar y pegar).

Answer (score 0):

Tengo mis dudas con la cadena en cuestión, técnicamente el problema debería radicar en como sale la cadena desde **PHP**, creo que lo que se está haciendo es algo así:

> `$obj` es el objeto que se codifica en **JSON**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo que se debería hacer sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Explicación**

En la primera imágen simplemente concateno la cadena `Datos` al string de salida de la función `json_encode` de **PHP**.
En **Javascript** el método `parse` del objeto `JSON` encontrará un error porque no reconocerá bajo ninguna circunstancia a la cadena `Datos`. Entonces una solución simple, es codificar el objeto en cuestión (segunda imágen) en un [arreglo asociativo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) desde **PHP**, poniendo la cadena `Datos` como clave y al objeto que debe ser convertido en **JSON** como índice (variable llamada `$obj` en la segunda imágen).

> Debo mencionar que para ejemplificar en la respuesta, imprimí la cadena en `JSON` resultante usando la función `echo` de **PHP**, pero en tu código esto podría bien no ser necesariamente así.

Para más información, podrías revisar el siguiente enlace: [PHP: json_encode - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Gracias Federico, la cadena sale de un select de la base como un "Datos Array" al momento de ejecutar json_encode($result); es que toma la forma "  Datos [{"a":"xya","b":"xyb","c":"xyc"}] " - el fin es colocar cada dato en un elemento html - pero no logro sacarlo a objeto - ya que me dificulta por el enunciado "Datos"

Comment: ¿Me puedes mostrar la cadena en bruto sin usar la función `json_encode($result)`?

Comment: Sin hacer el encode en consola imprime así:  -  Datos Array   -

Comment: ¿Y en la fila de la base de datos que se muestra?

Comment: están los datos, y al poner json_encode, se visualizan - están bien es lo que debe arrojar, a excepción del Datos, que pierdo idea porque se está generando

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y poner una captura del código **PHP** en cuestión que saca los datos desde **SQL** y otra que recibe y codifica los datos?

Comment: hecho, listas las capturas

Comment: (En la primera captura) ¿me puedes mostrar el código del método `ejecutarSQL`?.
(En la segunda captura) ¿me puedes mostrar una captura del resultado `var_dump($result);`?

Lo que quiero saber es si el método `ejecutarSQL` pone el texto `Datos`.

Comment: Añadí el código de ejecutarSQL como imagen- el var_dump($result)  arroja lo siguiente:  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(3) "xya"
    ["b"]=>
    string(3) "xyb"
    ["c"]=>
    string(3) "xyc"
  }
}

Comment: El `var_dump` muestra que el objeto esta bien, has un `var_dump($jsons);` en vez de `echo $jsons` para ver que sale, no veo que halla problema, adicionalmente, anda a la consola del navegador y ubica el request en la pestaña `Network`, y ve que arroja el servidor. Deberías tener la petición en crudo, sin procesar por **Javascript**, ya que si el `var_dump($result)` muestra que todo está bien, y ahora descartamos `json_encode`, el problema debería estar en el front end (por descarte).